# Tektons git-clone is ignoring my ssh config

Tags: git, ssh, git-clone, tekton

I'm following the [Clone a git repository with Tekton](https://tekton.dev/docs/how-to-guides/clone-repository) tutorial and try to clone a git repo using ssh.

The pipeline works fine, using HTTPS but for ssh it's complaining that the ssh configuration is missing. From the logs I can see that it finds the secret with the ssh files. But some lines later it complains that there' no ssh configuration.

Any ideas?

My pipeline.yaml (unchanged from the tutorial)

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: clone-read
spec:
  description: | 
    This pipeline clones a git repo, then echoes the README file to the stout.
  params:
  - name: repo-url
    type: string
    description: The git repo URL to clone from.
  workspaces:
  - name: shared-data
    description: | 
      This workspace contains the cloned repo files, so they can be read by the
      next task.
  - name: git-credentials
    description: My ssh credentials
  tasks:
  - name: fetch-source
    taskRef:
      name: git-clone
    workspaces:
    - name: output
      workspace: shared-data
    - name: ssh-directory
      workspace: git-credentials
    params:
    - name: url
      value: $(params.repo-url)
    - name: verbose
      value: true
  - name: show-readme
    runAfter: ["fetch-source"]
    taskRef:
      name: show-readme
    workspaces:
    - name: source
      workspace: shared-data
```

My pipelinerun.yaml (unchanged from the tutorial):

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  generateName: clone-read-run-
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: clone-read
  podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532
  workspaces:
  - name: shared-data
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
  - name: git-credentials
    secret:
      secretName: git-credentials
  params:
  - name: repo-url
    value: git@github.com:tektoncd/website.git
```

My sevret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: git-credentials
data:
  id_rsa: LS0tLS...
  id_rsa.pub: c3NoLXJ...
  known_hosts: Z2l0aH...
```

Logoutput:

```
 $ tkn pipelinerun logs clone-read-run-72zlj -f
[fetch-source : clone] + '[' false '=' true ]
[fetch-source : clone] + '[' true '=' true ]
[fetch-source : clone] + cp -R /workspace/ssh-directory /home/git/.ssh
[fetch-source : clone] + chmod 700 /home/git/.ssh
[fetch-source : clone] + chmod -R 400 /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa /home/git/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/git/.ssh/known_hosts
[fetch-source : clone] + '[' false '=' true ]
[fetch-source : clone] + CHECKOUT_DIR=/workspace/output/
[fetch-source : clone] + '[' true '=' true ]
[fetch-source : clone] + cleandir
[fetch-source : clone] + '[' -d /workspace/output/ ]
[fetch-source : clone] + rm -rf '/workspace/output//*'
[fetch-source : clone] + rm -rf '/workspace/output//.[!.]*'
[fetch-source : clone] + rm -rf '/workspace/output//..?*'
[fetch-source : clone] + test -z
[fetch-source : clone] + test -z
[fetch-source : clone] + test -z
[fetch-source : clone] + git config --global --add safe.directory /workspace/output
[fetch-source : clone] + /ko-app/git-init '-url=git@github.com:tektoncd/website.git' '-revision=' '-refspec=' '-path=/workspace/output/' '-sslVerify=true' '-submodules=true' '-depth=1' '-sparseCheckoutDirectories='
[fetch-source : clone] {"level":"warn","ts":1671382236.5119827,"caller":"git/git.go:271","msg":"URL(\"git@github.com:tektoncd/website.git\") appears to need SSH authentication but no SSH credentials have been provided"}
[fetch-source : clone] {"level":"error","ts":1671382237.3406594,"caller":"git/git.go:53","msg":"Error running git [fetch --recurse-submodules=yes --depth=1 origin --update-head-ok --force ]: exit status 128\ngit@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.\n","stacktrace":"github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git.run\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git/git.go:53\ngithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git.Fetch\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/git/git.go:156\nmain.main\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init/main.go:53\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:250"}
[fetch-source : clone] {"level":"fatal","ts":1671382237.340791,"caller":"git-init/main.go:54","msg":"Error fetching git repository: failed to fetch []: exit status 128","stacktrace":"main.main\n\tgithub.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init/main.go:54\nruntime.main\n\truntime/proc.go:250"}
```

Comment: The `secret.yaml` you show in your question matches the sample one in the page, but it needs to *not* match the sample. Did you generate actual keys and install them on GitHub and then put them in your `secret.yaml`?

Comment: No, it does not match the sample one. And yes, I generated keys on GitHub. I can to a SSH clone one the command line just fine.

Comment: OK, the only other suggestion I have at this point is to use Git's `core.sshCommand` (or environment SSH_COMMAND variable) to run `ssh -v` (insert as many extra `-v`s as you like) so that you can trace the ssh command that Git runs, to see why it's not happy with the ssh keys.

Comment: How can I do that? There's no such option for the git-clone task.

Comment: No idea, I've never used tekton. There must be some way to smuggle options in though, for debug purposes.

Comment: @BetaRide Have you got any luck on solving this?

Answer (score 1):

i have also face the same issue while testing the git-clone task and taskRun (the following files can be easily adapted with pipeline and pipelineRun).

The first problem is that the git-init docker image used by the git-clone task uses some hard-coded paths.  When changing the git-init docker image tag, there are some internal changes, like the user and the home folder (on newer image v0.40, the user is git, located at /home/git, on earlier image, nonroot at /home/nonroot).

As the git-clone-task is public and doesn't have a huge script, i have opted to edit it and remove unnecessary code.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: github-repo-credentials-secret
data:
  id_rsa: LS0tLS...
  known_hosts: Z2l0aH...
```

---

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
 name: github-repo-clone-task
spec:
 workspaces:
   - name: clonedDirectoryFolder
     description: Github cloned repo shared folder
   - name: githubSshFolder
     description: GitHub SSH credentials shared folder
 params:
   - name: repoUrl
     description: Repository URL to clone from.
     type: string
   - name: revision
     description: Branch, tag .... etc
     type: string
     default: "main"
   - name: deleteExisting
     description: Clean out the contents of the destination directory if it already exists before cloning.
     type: string
     default: "true"
   - name: userHome
     description: Absolute path to the user's home directory.
     type: string
     default: "/home/git"
   - name: gitInitImage
     description: The image providing the git-init binary that this Task runs.
     type: string
     default: "gcr.io/tekton-releases/github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init:v0.25.0"
 steps:
   - name: clone-git-repo-ssh
     image: "$(params.gitInitImage)"
     #image: "gcr.io/tekton-releases/github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init:v0.21.0"
     env:
       - name: PARAM_URL
         value: $(params.repoUrl)
       - name: PARAM_REVISION
         value: $(params.revision)
       - name: WORKSPACE_OUTPUT_PATH
         value: $(workspaces.clonedDirectoryFolder.path)
       - name: PARAM_DELETE_EXISTING
         value: $(params.deleteExisting)
       - name: WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_BOUND
         value: $(workspaces.githubSshFolder.bound)
       - name: WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_PATH
         value: $(workspaces.githubSshFolder.path)
       - name: PARAM_USER_HOME
         value: $(params.userHome)
       - name: GIT_SSH_COMMAND
       #  value: "ssh -i $(params.userHome)/.ssh/id_rsa -F /dev/null -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'"  # both values work
         value: "ssh -i $(params.userHome)/.ssh/id_rsa"
     script: |
       #!/usr/bin/env sh
       set -eu

       set -x
       
       if [ "${WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_BOUND}" = "true" ] ; then

          cp -R "${WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_PATH}" "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh

          chmod 700 "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh

          chmod -R 400 "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh/*
          
          chmod 600 "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh/config         
                   
        fi
        
       # ln -s "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh /tekton/creds  # uncomment this to get rid of this warming: appears to need SSH authentication but no SSH credentials have been provided
       
       CHECKOUT_DIR="${WORKSPACE_OUTPUT_PATH}"

       cleandir() {

          # Delete any existing contents of the repo directory if it exists.

          # We don't just "rm -rf ${CHECKOUT_DIR}" because ${CHECKOUT_DIR} might be "/"

          # or the root of a mounted volume.

          if [ -d "${CHECKOUT_DIR}" ] ; then

            # Delete non-hidden files and directories

            rm -rf "${CHECKOUT_DIR:?}"/*

            # Delete files and directories starting with . but excluding ..

            rm -rf "${CHECKOUT_DIR}"/.[!.]*

            # Delete files and directories starting with .. plus any other character

            rm -rf "${CHECKOUT_DIR}"/..?*

          fi

        }


        if [ "${PARAM_DELETE_EXISTING}" = "true" ] ; then

          cleandir || true

        fi
        
       git config --global --add safe.directory "${WORKSPACE_OUTPUT_PATH}"
       
       # uncomment the two lines below if the GIT_SSH_COMMAND env variable is not set
       
       #eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
        
       #ssh-add "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh/id_rsa
       
       /ko-app/git-init \
         -url="${PARAM_URL}" \
         -revision="${PARAM_REVISION}" \
         -path="${CHECKOUT_DIR}"
       cd "${CHECKOUT_DIR}"
       EXIT_CODE="$?"
       if [ "${EXIT_CODE}" != 0 ] ; then
         exit "${EXIT_CODE}"
       fi
       # Verify clone is success by reading readme file.
       cat ${CHECKOUT_DIR}/README.md
```

---

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TaskRun
metadata:
  name: github-repo-clone-task-run
spec:
  workspaces:
   - name: clonedDirectoryFolder
     volumeClaimTemplate:
       spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
   - name: githubSshFolder
     secret:
       secretName: github-repo-credentials-secret
  params:
    - name: repoUrl
      value: "git@github.com:tektoncd/website.git"  #git ssh clone Url
    - name: revision
      value: "main"
    - name: userHome
      value: "/home/git"
      #value: "/root"  # use this when the security context is set root
      #value: "/home/nonroot"  # use this value for ealier git-init:v0.29.0
    - name: gitInitImage
      #value: "alpine/git:latest"
      value: "gcr.io/tekton-releases/github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init:v0.40.2"
      #value: "gcr.io/tekton-releases/github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/cmd/git-init:v0.29.0"  # if you use this image, set the userHome to /home/nonroot
  taskRef:
    name: github-repo-clone-task
  # uncomment this part to run the task as root
  
  #podTemplate:
  #  securityContext:
  #    runAsNonRoot: false
  #    runAsUser: 0
```

The **GIT_SSH_COMMAND** environment variable is used to force git to use the provided private key.

Answer (score 0):

I just complete my answer in case you want to use the alpine git docker image. In this case there are few modifications on the previous Yaml Files.

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
 name: github-repo-clone-task-git-alpine
spec:
 workspaces:
   - name: clonedDirectoryFolder
     description: Github cloned repo shared folder
   - name: githubSshFolder
     description: GitHub SSH credentials shared folder
 params:
   - name: repoUrl
     description: Repository URL to clone from.
     type: string
   - name: revision
     description: Branch, tag .... etc
     type: string
     default: "main"
   - name: deleteExisting
     description: Clean out the contents of the destination directory if it already exists before cloning.
     type: string
     default: "true"
   - name: userHome
     description: Absolute path to the user's home directory.
     type: string
     default: "/root"
   - name: gitInitImage
     description: The image providing the git-init binary that this Task runs.
     type: string
     default: "alpine/git:latest"
 steps:
   - name: clone-git-repo-ssh
     image: "$(params.gitInitImage)"
     env:
       - name: PARAM_URL
         value: $(params.repoUrl)
       - name: PARAM_REVISION
         value: $(params.revision)
       - name: WORKSPACE_OUTPUT_PATH
         value: $(workspaces.clonedDirectoryFolder.path)
       - name: PARAM_DELETE_EXISTING
         value: $(params.deleteExisting)
       - name: WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_BOUND
         value: $(workspaces.githubSshFolder.bound)
       - name: WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_PATH
         value: $(workspaces.githubSshFolder.path)
       - name: PARAM_USER_HOME
         value: $(params.userHome)
       - name: GIT_SSH_COMMAND
       #  value: "ssh -i $(params.userHome)/.ssh/id_rsa -F /dev/null -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'"  # both values work
         value: "ssh -i $(params.userHome)/.ssh/id_rsa"
     script: |
       #!/usr/bin/env sh
       set -eu

       set -x
       
       if [ "${WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_BOUND}" = "true" ] ; then

          cp -R "${WORKSPACE_SSH_DIRECTORY_PATH}" "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh

          chmod 700 "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh

          chmod -R 400 "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh/*
          
          chmod 600 "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh/config         
                   
        fi
       
       CHECKOUT_DIR="${WORKSPACE_OUTPUT_PATH}"

       cleandir() {

          # Delete any existing contents of the repo directory if it exists.

          # We don't just "rm -rf ${CHECKOUT_DIR}" because ${CHECKOUT_DIR} might be "/"

          # or the root of a mounted volume.

          if [ -d "${CHECKOUT_DIR}" ] ; then

            # Delete non-hidden files and directories

            rm -rf "${CHECKOUT_DIR:?}"/*

            # Delete files and directories starting with . but excluding ..

            rm -rf "${CHECKOUT_DIR}"/.[!.]*

            # Delete files and directories starting with .. plus any other character

            rm -rf "${CHECKOUT_DIR}"/..?*

          fi

        }


        if [ "${PARAM_DELETE_EXISTING}" = "true" ] ; then

          cleandir || true

        fi
       
       # uncomment the two lines below if the GIT_SSH_COMMAND env variable is not set
       
       #eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
        
       #ssh-add "${PARAM_USER_HOME}"/.ssh/id_rsa
       
       git clone "${PARAM_URL}" --branch="${PARAM_REVISION}" "${CHECKOUT_DIR}"
       cd "${CHECKOUT_DIR}"
       EXIT_CODE="$?"
       if [ "${EXIT_CODE}" != 0 ] ; then
         exit "${EXIT_CODE}"
       fi
       # Verify clone is success by reading readme file.
       cat ${CHECKOUT_DIR}/README.md
```

---

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TaskRun
metadata:
  name: github-repo-clone-task-run-git-alpine
spec:
  workspaces:
   - name: clonedDirectoryFolder
     volumeClaimTemplate:
       spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
   - name: githubSshFolder
     secret:
       secretName: github-repo-credentials-secret
  params:
    - name: repoUrl
      value: "git@github.com:tektoncd/website.git"  #git ssh clone Url
    - name: revision
      value: "main"
    - name: userHome
      value: "/root"
    - name: gitInitImage
      value: "alpine/git:latest"
  taskRef:
    name: github-repo-clone-task-git-alpine
```

Note that this image uses the root user, there is another image with a non root user available : [gcr.io/tekton-releases/dogfooding/alpine-git-nonroot:latest](https://gcr.io/tekton-releases/dogfooding/alpine-git-nonroot:latest), to use this image in these Yaml files, just the gitInitImage parameter value in TaskRun and also set the *userHome* to */home/nonroot* .

Additional information can found at this github page: https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/blob/main/examples/v1beta1/taskruns/authenticating-git-commands.yaml